# saving the state of UITableviewcell accessoryView

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, uitableview, uibutton

I have a checkbox as an accessoryView in my UITableViewCell. When I click on the checkbox, it gets checkmarked and vise versa. But When i scroll down out of view and scroll back, the checkbox is gone.
I am wondering what are some ways to save the state of my button?

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
        cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

    if([tableView isEqual:self.myTableView]){
        static NSString *TableViewIdentifier = @"MyCells";
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:TableViewIdentifier];
        if(cell == nil){
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                         reuseIdentifier:TableViewIdentifier];
        } 
        //configure the cell
        checkbox = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        CGRect checkboxRect = CGRectMake(135, 150, 36, 36);
        [checkbox setFrame:checkboxRect];  
        [checkbox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unselected@2x.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [checkbox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected@2x.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

        /*if (checkbox.state == UIControlStateNormal) {
            [checkbox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unselected@2x.png"]forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        }else if(checkbox.state == UIControlStateSelected){
            [checkbox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected@2x.png"]forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        }*/

        [checkbox addTarget:self action:@selector(checkboxClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        cell.accessoryView = checkbox;


        NSString *group;
        NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

        switch (indexPath.section) {
            case 0:
                group = [suggestedPeople objectAtIndex:row];
                cell.textLabel.text = group;
                break;
            case 1:
                group = [aArray objectAtIndex:row];
                cell.textLabel.text = group;
                break;
            case 2:
                group = [bArray objectAtIndex:row];
                cell.textLabel.text = group;
                break;
            case 3:
                group = [cArray objectAtIndex:row];
                cell.textLabel.text = group;
                break;
            case 4:
                group = [dArray objectAtIndex:row];
                cell.textLabel.text = group;
                break;
            case 5:
                group = [eArray objectAtIndex:row];
                cell.textLabel.text = group;
                break;
        }
    }
    return cell;
}
```

EDIT:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier{
if(self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]){
    checkbox = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    CGRect checkboxRect = CGRectMake(135, 150, 36, 36);
    [checkbox setFrame:checkboxRect];  
    [checkbox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unselected@2x.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [checkbox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected@2x.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

}
return self;}
```

Comment: That definitely shouldn't be happening. Can you post some code? Particularly your cellForRowAtIndexPath function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for posting the code. Right, your problem is that you are creating UIButton instances in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method. This isn't allowed (or rather, odd things will happen as you've noticed). You should create a TableViewCell subclass and add the button there, or create a XIB for the table cell and load that.

Check out this post for some help with this:

http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=545061

Comment: i have another class and put the UIbutton to it, may i ask what is the syntax to add it to my ViewController?

Comment: It's okay to create/add a cell's subview in cellForRowAtIndex path, but give the new subview a tag, and do it only if dequeue returns nil.  If you get a dequeued cell, then that's one you built already, and the subview should be found with viewWithTag:, not created.

Comment: Ah.. interesting! I didn't know you could do that, thanks @danh.